# Retrieve data from an array-like object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am new to Javascript and struggling with the following question:
I have Rails code with an array of hashes in a controller. I am passing the array to the view and iterating through it with the following code:

```
<div id="coordinates">
  <%- @points.each_with_index do |point, index| %>
    <%= "The additional point number #{index+1} found for the parabola has the following co-ordinates: #{point}"%>
    <%= content_tag :div, '', class: "element_name", data: {x: point.each_key.first} do %>
    <% end %>
    <br>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The idea is to find all elements with "element_name" class, iterate through them and retrieve data. However, this doesn't seem to work. I can retrieve all elements with a required class name, iterate through them, but not retrieve data for x from each element.

NOTE: The issue is not with getting elements in a form of array-like object or iterating through them, but with retrieving data for each element. Specifically, I need to retrieve the data for x attribute.

I have tried the following in my JS file:

```
var index;
var a =  Array.prototype.slice.call($('.element_name'), 0)
for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
  a[index].data('x'); }
```

The error I'm getting is "Uncaught TypeError: a[index].data is not a function".

Are there any other ways to retrieve that data from each element of an array-like object (HTML collection)?

I'm still a newbie to Javascript and programming in general, apologies if it's something simple that I've missed.

Comment: Why not `$('.element_name').first()` or `$('.element_name:first')`

Comment: Well, this simply selects a first object on a page with "element_name" class but doesn't really retrieve data from it. I will edit the question to make it more obvious. The issue is not with retrieving elements or iterating through them, but with retrieving data for each element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `a[index]` is not a jQuery instance of element then it doesn't have the `data()` function. You can try `$(a[index]).data('x')`.